# Minimum for the set of roots of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a<b$ be real numbers and $I :=[a,b]$. Now let $f:I\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function on I, with a root in $I$. I need to show that a mnimum exists for the set $M:=\{x\in[a,b] : f(x)=0\}$.

I am genuinly stumped. Is this some application of the intermediate value theorem? Is proving that the set is closed sufficient?

Answer (score 2):

It is clear that $M$ is bounded. Let's see that it is closed. Indeed, let $(x_n)_n\subset M$ such that $x_n\to y$.We want to see that $y\in M$. We know that $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n$, so by continuity, $f(y)=f(\lim_n x_n)=\lim_n f(x_n) =0$ and we have $y\in M$.

Hence, $M$ is compact and your minimum exists.